# PHP how to display plain URL

Tags: php, javascript, url, seo

I am using some Javascript and PHP to get the Browser Viewport and dynamically serve a suitable layout based on visitor's browser / device. My `index.php` file is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['width']) AND isset($_GET['height'])) {
  $layoutWidth = $_GET['width'];
      if ( $layoutWidth >= 240 && $layoutWidth <= 900 ) {
        require_once('layout1.php');
      } else {
         require_once('layout2.php');
      }
} else {
  echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
  echo "  location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}"
            . "&width=\" + document.documentElement.clientWidth;\n";
  echo "</script>\n";
  exit();
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**The output url is like this:**

`http://mydomain.com/index.php?&width=1600&height=812`

**What I am looking for is a method to make this URL look like:**

`http://mydomain.com/`

**Is it possible to do so? If yes then how?**

Any PHP or Plain JavaScript solution will do

*(No jQuery or MooTools or any such libraries please because this is the only JavaScript function in my entire website and it wont make any sense to load 50 to 100 KB of library just to fulfill this small task.)*

Please help

Comment: Does not your script result in an infinite loop? EDIT: NO it does not! :)

Comment: Ever heard of [media queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/)?

Comment: If you want to check out what type of visitor is viewing your page, you could check out [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I do think my suggestion of wurfl is a valid one, since with it you can detect what kind of visitor (desktop, mobile, ...) is viewing your page on the serverside and decide what kind of content you return.

Comment: Well, if you are allready detecting visitors, then I would store the type of visitor in their session and base your decision of contentdelivery on that.  I would not store that information in your urls.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10704/discussion-between-zombaya-and-vikram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use .htaccess to rewrite the URL (code excludes common resource types and index.php loop):

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://mydomain.com/
```

Then use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to access the actually requested URI from which you can parse your height and width values. For example

```
$height = 0;
$width = 0;
$requestParts = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$requestParts = explode('&', $requestParts['1']);
foreach ($requestParts as $requestPart) {
    $getVarParts = explode('=', $requestPart);
    if ($getVarParts['0'] == 'height') {
        $height = $getVarParts['1'];
    } else if ($getVarParts['0'] == 'width') {
        $width = $getVavParts['1'];
    }
}
```